# Installing php-decimal in MacOS arm64e and can't get libmpdec

Tags: php, decimal, pecl

I've just upgraded to a MacBook with the M1 and when installing php-decimal with `pecl install decimal`, I receive the following error:

```
checking for libmpdec custom path... no
checking for libmpdec library in default path... found in /usr/local/lib
checking for libmpdec headers in default path... found in /usr/local/include
checking for mpd_version in -lmpdec... no
configure: error: Please check your version of libmpdec (2.4+)
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/temp/decimal/configure --with-php-config=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.0.8/bin/php-config' failed
```

I've used homebrew to install libmpdec `brew install mpdecimal` and I can see the files at `usr/local/lib` - they are aliases to the homebrew location with these files:

- libmpdec++.a
- libmpdec++.2.5.1.dylib
- libmpdec.a
- libmpdec.2.5.1.dylib
- libmpdec++.dylib
- libmpdec++.3.dylib
- libmpdec.dylib
- libmpdec.3.dylib

I'm just out of ideas here.

Comment: Tried everything, had to recompile libmpdec from source and once I did that, it all worked completely magically with `pecl install decimal`. So getting it from brew failed, but building myself did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ancient magic is looking for whether a function named mpd_version to determine if your version of the library has that function.

As you apparently have version 2.5.1 and 3 installed somewhere it should find it. But the error message is one that could result in an older version of the headers being present the directory /usr/local/include.

Can you look at the file mpdecimal.h in /usr/local/include to see if that file is present in there, and contains a definition of the function mpd_version in it.

Though it may also be failing at the linking step. You should be able to dump out which symbols are present in the lib by running `nm -gC libmpdec.a` or similar.

Comment: btw I don't have a M1 to test on - you could send me one if you like - but the manual page for nm is here https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/nm/ in case that isn't the right flags.

Comment: Thanks so much for the hints @Danack. The version from homebrew was definitely the right one and I couldn't find any indication of another one, but apparently it just had to be manually compiled and installed. Once I did that it just worked with no more hassle ¯\_(ツ)_/¯