# Cannot install decimal PHP extension on macOS with M1 – "Could not find libmpdec"

Tags: php, decimal, apple-m1, pecl

I tried to install the `decimal` PHP extension using `pecl` because I need it for an existing project. On my new M1 machine, I got the following error:

```sh
$ pecl install decimal
[...]
checking for libmpdec library in default path... Could not find libmpdec
configure: error: Please reinstall libmpdec
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/temp/decimal/configure --with-php-config=/opt/homebrew/bin/php-config' failed
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After researching online, I found these threads describing similar issues:

- [Installing php-decimal in MacOS arm64e and can't get libmpdec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69999108/installing-php-decimal-in-macos-arm64e-and-cant-get-libmpdec)
- https://www.reddit.com/r/PHPhelp/comments/nmryxz/trouble_installing_php_extensions_with_valet_and/

Since both threads did not include a compact explanation of what I needed to do to fix the issue, I decided to try and summarize it here.

When `pecl` tries to install the `decimal` extension, the `libmpdec` library is not found in the default library path. The installer tries to find the library in `/usr/local/lib/` while Homebrew installs it in `/opt/homebrew/lib/`. To help the installer get up to speed, create symlinks for the library components and two header files:

```bash
sudo mkdir /usr/local/lib
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/lib/libmpdec++.2.5.1.dylib /usr/local/lib/libmpdec++.2.5.1.dylib
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/lib/libmpdec++.3.dylib /usr/local/lib/libmpdec++.3.dylib
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/lib/libmpdec++.a /usr/local/lib/libmpdec++.a
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/lib/libmpdec++.dylib /usr/local/lib/libmpdec++.dylib
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/lib/libmpdec.2.5.1.dylib /usr/local/lib/libmpdec.2.5.1.dylib
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/lib/libmpdec.3.dylib /usr/local/lib/libmpdec.3.dylib
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/lib/libmpdec.a /usr/local/lib/libmpdec.a
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/lib/libmpdec.dylib /usr/local/lib/libmpdec.dylib

sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/include/decimal.hh /usr/local/include/decimal.hh
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/include/mpdecimal.h /usr/local/include/mpdecimal.h
```

After creating the symlinks, try to install the `decimal` extension again:

```bash
pecl install decimal
```

The installation should now work as expected.

Comment: This absolutely helped me, thank you!

Comment: Great research. I did it without symlinks by settings some variables: `LIBMPDEC_DIR=/opt/homebrew/lib LIBMPDEC_INC=/opt/homebrew/include pecl install decimal` (see https://github.com/php-decimal/ext-decimal/blob/v1.4.0/config.m4)

Comment: Before running `sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/include/decimal.hh /usr/local/include/decimal.hh` run `sudo mkdir /usr/local/include`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply change the directory that the pecl wants to file libmpdec and everything should work work fine:

`LIBMPDEC_DIR=/opt/homebrew/lib LIBMPDEC_INC=/opt/homebrew/include pecl install decimal`

```
Installing '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.2.8/pecl/20220829/decimal.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/decimal-1.4.0
Extension decimal enabled in php.ini
```