# How to install the PHP Decimal extension on non-Windows OS

Tags: php, pecl

[PHP Decimal](https://php-decimal.io/) seems to be the only good alternative to bcmath. The name refers to both a wrapper library as well as a PHP extension. The extension itself depends on libmpdec.

> Dependencies
>
> - PHP 7
> - [libmpdec 2.4+](http://www.bytereef.org/mpdecimal/quickstart.html)

Installation instructions:

> The easiest way to install the extension is to use PECL:
>
> `pecl install decimal`
>
> If you are using phpbrew:
>
> ```
> phpbrew ext install decimal
> phpbrew ext enable  decimal
> ```

Which seems easy enough.

I had some trouble getting PECL to work on Windows; which was not a problem because you can just download the DLLs from [the PECL site](https://pecl.php.net/package/decimal). If you are on another OS (such as any future production environment, in my case), no such luck.

It seems that everywhere else, PECL tries to compile the extension from source (phpize). Which in turn requires libmpdec to be present on the system in some way. [Other people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70101255/cannot-install-decimal-php-extension-on-macos-with-m1-could-not-find-libmpdec) seem to have gotten that to work.

My problem here is that I cannot find any documentation on how exactly libmpdec should be installed, or where it needs to be already present for the installation to work, or really just *what* needs to be present. It sounds like it might simply be an apt-get/yum/etc. package? If so, which one? Or something else? Is anything more elaborate required here?

Can someone tell me what steps (or assumptions) I am missing?

Comment: That link literally tells you how to install it on linux systems and MacOS. If you're having problems, outline the steps you tried and the exact error you're having. Though installing libraries would be more suited for https://superuser.com or https://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: You are right, this might be a question for Superuser. The OS is probably only ever going to be Linux, but I thought it would be better to ask generally. Which link are you referring to?

Comment: The [libmpdec 2.4+ link](http://www.bytereef.org/mpdecimal/quickstart.html) that you linked under dependencies

Comment: Ah okay. My problem is that the link explains how to build it, but not what to do with it to make PECL able to actually interact with it. Am I missing something in that regard?

Comment: It shouldn't need anything. once the library is installed successfully, when you run pecl, it will check the dependencies again and see that it's installed.

Comment: Okay. Not having worked with make before, I assumed it only acts as part of a compile pipeline here. You are saying it should also distribute any generated files to their appropriate locations?

Comment: `make` compiles the binary. It doesn't mention `make install`, which usually installs it into the right spots.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work it out. The parts I was missing were:

- `./configure` is supposed to be a bash file that does some initial setup
- `make install` not only compiles libmpdec but then also installs it to the appropriate directories (thanks for clarifying, @aynber)

After that, `pecl install decimal` should be able to do its job.